# New Find & Replace Box

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have found myself with a new find and replace facility within visual studio that appears in the top right of my IDE.

I think it has come down as part of a nu-get package (probably alongside something else).  I much prefer my old find and replace dialog box.

Does anyone know how to turn this off and get my old Find & Replace box back?

Comment: Worth noting that nu-get packages don't install things that would affect your IDE.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's probably `Quick Find` in [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/).

Look for `Tools Options Support` on the page above and turn off `Quick Find` from there.

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  It is the new Quick Find function.  I found it in Tools|Options|Productivity Productivity Power Tools.  I will mark this as the answer. My apologies to any of the guys working on the productivity power tools package which is generally brilliant but I just couldnt get along with this one.

Comment: Yea, I meant Quick Find. I just got up, not thinking straight. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... exactly what I was looking for. It was pissing me off that my keyboard support wasn't all there in the new Quick Find functionality.